# Can't figure out the reason for the output?

Tags: c

```
//Language C
int main()
{
    int a[5]={0};
    for(int i=0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
}
```

The output of the following was 1000 in gcc. But I thought it should print 1 and rest garbage values as I have not assigned values to other array locations.

If compiler version is not taken in account, is my thinking right? Or I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard (citing the latest C11 draft N1570 here) explains this quite well.

**§6.7.9 Initialization, p21**:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration**.

(emphasis mine)

so, every element except `a[0]` in your code is initialized *implicitly*. Now let's look what that means:

**§6.7.9 Initialization, p10**:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object **that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly**, then:
>   — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>   — **if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero**;
>   — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>   and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>   — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

(again, emphasis mine)

so, `a[1]` to `a[4]` are initialized to `0` -- type `int` is an *arithmetic type*.

Comment: Thanks for giving clarity.

Comment: @prasoon you're welcome. The C standard can be a bit hard to read at first, but it's the one **definitive** reference :) Btw, if your assumption would have been correct, your program would have been "undefined" -- you're not allowed to use uninitialized values and your program is free to do "whatever" if you do ...

Comment: I will try to read C standard though the use so many standard terms makes it so complex. Thanks once again.